# Powershell - New-Variable "-name" defined by function variable

Tags: powershell, variables

I want to have a function in which the result is stored in a variable where the function defines the variable name - essentially this:

```
function testfunction ($varname,$text){
    $readhost = read-host -prompt "$text"
    new-variable -name $varname -value $readhost
}
```

though when entering:

```
testfunction outputvar sampletext

get-variable -name outputvar
```

I just get an error that the variable "outputvar" doesnt exist. what am I missing here? Tried a number of other stuff but nothing seemed to work - what i want in the end is a variable that is named "outputvar" that contains the prompt input, just to clarify.

Comment: This is due to scoping. Variables created with a function are scoped (only accessible) to that function. You can use `$global:` to create a global variable, but it would be better to just return a value to a variable. I'll write an answer with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is due to scoping. The variable created via `New-Variable` is (by default) scoped so that it is only accessible within your function. You can override the scope via the `-Scope` parameter:

```
function testfunction ($varname,$text){
    $readhost = read-host -prompt "$text"
    new-variable -name $varname -value $readhost -scope Script
}
```

This changes the scope to Script and so the variable is now accessible outside of your function. Defining non-standard scopes for your variables isn't very good practice however. You should instead just be doing this:

```
function testfunction ($text){
    read-host -prompt "$text"
}

$outputvar = testfunction sampletext
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried to keep the variable in the function so i dont have to repeat it for every use for the function - just out of curiousity, why exactly is it not a good practice?

edit: i used $readhost = read-host in the first place because i was using a do - while loop though, but i guess that could work with a pipeline instead

Comment: Its just because scopes exist for a reason, to keep variables where they are needed and avoid confusion/errors that could occur if the same variable name was used elsewhere. If you wanted to loop around `read-host` you could still do that and then just output its value at the end: `while (-not $readhost) { $readhost = read-host }; $readhost`

Comment: forgot to add, im looping it while input is $null - im not quite sure how i should implement your example code, can you explain a little what this does?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-OutVariable` common parameter. To have your function support common parameters, add the `CmdletBinding` attribute decorator to the `param` block:

```
function Test-Function {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param($text)

  return Read-Host -Prompt $text
}

Test-Function -OutVariable sampletext |Out-Null
$sampletext
```